# Equivalent of org.hornetq.api.core.client.ClientMessage.setBodyInputStream in IBM MQSeries

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

In the following  [JBoss/HornetQ user manual page](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.2.Final/user-manual/en/html/large-messages.html) you can see how HornetQ provides a mechanism for streaming data to a Message for a Queue using a java.io.InputStream. A JMS version of the same code is given. Has anyone come across an equivalent using IBM MQSeries / WebsphereMQ?

Say I have a large amount of data to place in the JMS Message which to me is just a stream of bytes. In the Hornet example, the stream is only read when the message is sent, so if it is, say a FileInputStream, then we only need enough memory to buffer a chunk of the bytes. I can use a javax.jms.BytesMessage to send in chunks of bytes and use the BytesMessage to buffer them. The problem with this is that the IBM implementation of BytesMessage (com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsBytesMessageImpl) has to cache them until the Message is sent and if that is a large amount of data it is a problem. Worse it appears that although I am only sending bytes, the IBM implementation appears to keep duplicate copies, one in a BytesArrayOutputStream the other in a DataOutputStream.

Comment: I have posted this on an MQSeries BB. See http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=346958#346958. There are some answers there. Since I am not an MQSeries implementor, I will leave it to one of them to answer.

Answer (score 1):

In WebSphere MQ the closest thing to what you describe is a [reference message](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fg12740_.htm).  The method described in the Infocenter requires custom programming of channel exits to grab the filesystem object and put it into a message before it is transmitted over the channel.  A complementary exit on the remote side saves the payload to a file and puts a reference to the file in the message that is returned to the app.

We also have programs in WMQ that take STDIN or a pipe at one end and put messages to a queue on the other end.  A pair of these can act as a pipe through which line-oriented ASCII data flows between processes on separate machines.  However, there's no JMS implementation of this and it doesn't work too well for binary data.

Answer (score 0):

In WMQ, we have concept of Group and Segment.
Segmentation is supported in all OS except Z/OS.

Check for details here [Segmentation In WMQ](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzal.doc/fg12700_.htm)

Make use of GroupId, MsgSeqNumber, and Offset while putting the message.

While getting the message if you give **MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG** in GMO, then all segments are joined automatically according to the MsgSeqNumber  and

> you will get a single message on the recieving application with a
>   single GET.